# how to create random numbers in mysql events?

Tags: mysql, events

```
INSERT into rate values(NULL,'admin@admin.com','2020-12-14 00:27:30','0.5','1.0','1.3','1.6','2.2','2.8','3.3','4.0','5.0','5.5')
```

I want to get random numbers in these fields to auto-generate and insert automatically by this event.

Comment: So, you need insert row with 10 random numbers between 0 and 10, right?

Comment: Yes, I need rand() method to display decimal random numbers

Comment: This looks (in part) like a problem of poor schema design

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the RAND function. And use TRUNCATE on RAND for the precision count.

```
INSERT into rate values(NULL,'admin@admin.com','2020-12-14 00:27:30', TRUNCATE(1 * rand(), 2), TRUNCATE(2 * rand(), 2), TRUNCATE(1 * rand(), 2), ..., TRUNCATE(4 * rand(), 2),...)
```

Comment: This is useful also, but I need the random numbers in between ranges like in php we use rand(3,7)/10 it means that (0.3-0.7), can we use like that in this mysql event scheduler?

Comment: @Adeel Siddiqui - generate only the difference and add the minimum like **(rand() *7) +5**

Comment: INSERT into rate values(NULL,'admin@admin.com','2020-12-14 00:03:50', TRUNCATE(RAND()*(0.7-0.3)+0.3, 2), TRUNCATE(RAND()*(1.0-0.8)+0.8, 2), TRUNCATE(RAND()*(1.4-1.2)+1.2, 2),TRUNCATE(RAND()*(1.8-1.5)+1.5, 2),TRUNCATE(RAND()*(2.3-2.1)+2.1, 2),TRUNCATE(RAND()*(2.8-2.5)+2.5, 2),TRUNCATE(RAND()*(3.3-3.0)+3.0, 2),TRUNCATE(RAND()*(4.2-3.8)+3.8, 2),TRUNCATE( RAND()*(5.5-4.5)+4.5, 2),TRUNCATE(RAND()*(6.0-5.5)+5.5, 2));
This is what I want, THANKS